# Get screenshot of EGL DRM/KMS application

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, opengl, egl

How to get screenshot of graphical application programmatically? Application draw its window using EGL API via DRM/KMS.

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 and graphical application written using Qt 5.9.2 with EGLFS QPA backend. It started from first virtual terminal (if matters), then it switch display to output in full HD graphical mode.

When I use utilities (e.g. `fb2png`) which operates on `/dev/fb?`, then only textmode contents of first virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>) are saved as screenshot.

It is hardly, that there are EGL API to get contents of any buffer from context of another process (it would be insecure), but maybe there are some mechanism (and library) to get access to final output of GPU?

Comment: Maybe make a shim library that forwards EGL calls and load it with `LD_PRELOAD` when launching the application.

Comment: @Velkan Interesting idea, thanks. I need to see the screen even if process of graphical application is not responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. One way would be to get a screenshot from within your application, reading the contents of the back buffer with `glReadPixels()`. Or use [QQuickWindow::grabWindow()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwindow.html#grabWindow), which internally uses `glReadPixels()` in the correct way. This seems to be not an option for you, as you need to take a screenshot when the Qt app is frozen.
2. The other way would be to use the DRM API to map the framebuffer and then `memcpy` the mapped pixels. This is implemented in Chromium OS with Python and can be translated to C easily, see https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromiumos/platform/factory/+/367611. The DRM API can also be used by another process than the Qt UI process that does the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question, and I have fought this problem from several angles.

The problem is quite complex and dependant on platform, you seem to be running on EGL, which means embedded, and there you have few options unless your platform offers them.

The options you have are:

## glTexSubImage2D

[glTexSubImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) can copy several kinds of buffers from OpenGL textures to CPU memory. Unfortunatly it is not supported in GLES 2/3, **but** your embedded provider might support it via an extension. This is nice because you can either render to FBO or get the pixels from the specific texture you need. It also needs minimal code intervertion.

## glReadPixels

[glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3/html/glReadPixels.xhtml) is the most common way to download all or part of the GPU pixels which are already rendered. Albeit slow, it works on GLES and Desktop. On Desktop with a decent GPU is bearable up to interactive framerates, but beware on embedded it might be **really** slow as it stops your render thread to get the data (horrible framedrops ensured). You can save code as it can be made to work with minimal code modifications.

## Pixel Buffer Objects (PBO's)

Once you start doing real research [PBO's](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/graphics/f/discussions/6657/how-to-gain-performance-through-pbo-pixel-buffer-object-on-mali-t-880) appear here and there because they can be made to work asynchronously. They are also generally not supported in embedded but can work really well on desktop even on mediocre GPU's. Also a bit tricky to setup and require specific render modifications.

## Framebuffer

On embedded, sometimes you already render to the framebuffer, so go there and fetch the pixels. Also works on desktop. You can enven `mmap()` the buffer to a file and get partial contents easily. But beware in many embedded systems EGL does not work on the framebuffer but on a different 'overlay' so you might be snapshotting the background of it. Also to note some multimedia applications are run with UI's on the EGL and media players on the framebuffer. So if you only need to capture the video players this might work for you. In other cases there is EGL targeting a texture which is copied to the framebuffer, and it will also work just fine.

As far as I know render to texture and stream to a framebuffer is the way they made the sweet Qt UI you see on the [Ableton Push 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CdMvkBOUgs)
[image]

## More exotic Dispmanx/OpenWF

On some embedded systems (notably the Raspberry Pi and most Broadcom Videocore's) you have DispmanX. [Whichs is really interesting](https://jan.newmarch.name/RPi/Dispmanx/):

This is fun:

> The lowest level of accessing the GPU seems to be by an API called Dispmanx[...]

It continues...

> Just to give you total lack of encouragement from using Dispmanx there are hardly any examples and no serious documentation.

Basically DispmanX is very near to baremetal. So it is even deeper down than the framebuffer or EGL. Really interesting stuff because you can use `vc_dispmanx_snapshot()` and really get a snapshot of everything really fast. And by fast I mean I got 30FPS RGBA32 screen capture with no noticeable stutter on screen and about 4~6% of extra CPU overhead on a Rasberry Pi. Night and day because glReadPixels got was producing very noticeable framedrops even for 1x1 pixel capture.

That's pretty much what I've found.